# Setting a variable by editing the same variable

Tags: bash, sh

In linux,
is it safe setting a variable using the very same variable within expansion in its definition?

```
a='test'
a=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/e/T/')
```

Is expansion first executed and then assigned to a variable? i.e. Is it safe to do this?

e.g. this can't be done (in similar scenario) with files:

```
cat /run/test | sed 's/e/T/' > /run/test
```

Comment: It is safe in Linux.

Comment: "Linux" is completely irrelevant here, this is just about Bash. Or, about the standard POSIX shell. Which is it?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt, you are correct. This is my mistake.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt about both Linux, Shell and Bash, if they don't share same rules on this subject. So on linux console in general.

Comment: Bash is the same, regardless of the OS it runs on top and regardless of the terminal (if any!) it is displayed in. Also, a different shell on the same OS could behave differently.

Comment: @DegenWoW There is no "linux console in general"; the linux console is just a read/write device that provides input and output for an arbitrary process, which is *usually* a shell. The only important factor here is which shell we are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe setting a variable using the very same variable within expansion in its definition?

Yes, it is safe. The `$(...)` is expanded first, so the line becomes `a=something`. Then the list is executed. Because `$(..)` is expanded first, it is safe.

> this can't be done (in similar scenario) with files:

It has nothing to do with variable usage. Think about a moment about this case. Imagine you have a 1GB file on your harddrive. How can you *read* and *write*/*overwrite* the same file at the same time? Ex. `cat` reads part of the file, then `> /run/test` truncates the file to 0 bytes and overwrites it with new data. There is nothing for cat to read from anymore, the original file content does not exists.

Comment: Regardless of file size, it is not safe.

Comment: Whether `cat` is able to read anything before the other command truncates `/run/test` is undefined and subject to a race condition between the two commands in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

With files, you can use the ‘edit in place’ provided with many utilities, (e.g., -I for see, Perl). Behind the scenes they will either:

- rename the original to .bak or similar, and will generate the new file using the .bak as input, OR
- if no backup is needed, remove the old file before creating the new file, using file descriptor for reading.

You can roll you own with something like

```
   Sed file > file.new && my file.new file
```

Comment: Or, use `ed` to edit files instead of relying on the non-standard `-i` extension.